# Importing a DB file in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to install the reactome DB into Neo4j so I can make a graph from it. I keep getting the same error message regardless of my syntax. The DB folder is stored in `neo4J\bin\reactome`.

I have basically been using this cypher command and all sorts of permutations of it:

```
neo4j-admin restore --from=neo4j\bin\reactome --database= reactome.graphdb –force=true"
```

and, regardless of how I do it, I get this error leading me to think it is something more than the syntax:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'e': expected <init> (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"eo4j-admin restore --from=neo4j\bin\reactome  --database= reactome.graphdb –force=true""
 ^
```

Comment: ok that was helpful but not when i try to enter bash neo4j-admin restore --from=\reactome --database=reactome.graphdb –force=true"....nothing executes

Answer (score 0):

The [neo4j-admin](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/tools/neo4j-admin/) tool must be run from the *command line* -- it is NOT a Cypher operation.

Answer (score 0):

To install the Reactome DB with Neo4j, click on 'open folder/import' in Neo4j. Then go up one directory, and go to '/data/databases/graph.db/'. Dump all the contents of the Reactome graph DB folder (uncompressed) inside the directory.